# gcloud deployment-manager undefined properties: UndefinedError: 'properties' is undefined

Tags: properties, undefined, gcloud

There is sample code here that uses the following code snippet to handle undefined properties.

```
{% if properties["cidr"] is defined %}
  {% set cidr = properties["cidr"] %}
{% else %}
  {% set cidr = "10.10.0.0/16" %}
{% endif %}
```

[github deployment-manager example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/community/pbs/pbs.jinja)

However, when I attempt to use similar code:

```
{% if properties['prod'] is defined %}
  {% set machine_type = 'n1-highmem-8' %}
  {% set num_nodes = 3 %}
{% else %}
  {% set machine_type = 'g1-small' %}
  {% set num_nodes = 1 %}
{% endif %}
```

and deploy as follows:

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create xxx --template kubernetes.jinja --automatic-rollback-on-error --preview
```

I get the following error:

```
- code: MANIFEST_EXPANSION_USER_ERROR   location: /deployments/xxx/manifests/manifest-1597981115450   message: |-
    Manifest expansion encountered the following errors: Exception in kubernetes.jinja
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        return template.render(resource)
        return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "<template>", line 19, in top-level template code
        return obj[argument]
    UndefinedError: 'properties' is undefined
     Resource: kubernetes.jinja Resource: config
```

When I deploy with properties it works.

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create xxx --template kubernetes.jinja --automatic-rollback-on-error --preview --properties prod:false
```

**How can I setup a jinja script to have default values and/or detect missing properties without throwing an exception?**

UPDATE:

Adding ANY property, even a different one seems to be enough to have the script execute.  It appears the properties attribute is COMPLETELY missing by default!

gcloud deployment-manager deployments create xxx --template kubernetes.jinja --automatic-rollback-on-error --preview --properties adsfsdfsdf:Asdfasdfasdf

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `properties` either in the config that uses the template or when deploying from the command line.

See: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/define-template-properties

E.g.

```sh
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create xxx \
--template=kubernetes.jinja \
--properties=prod:...
```